# Best method to redirect a video stream to a Video Player (Like HTML5 video player)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to use asp.net API 2.1 to redirect a video stream.
I GET a URL with the Source video stream and need to port it (API respond) to a Video Player who can receive it and play it.

After research i found two option:

**1. Based on MemoryStream:**

```
     public async Task<FileStreamResult> Get(string SourceVideoURL)
            {
                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                byte[] b= await _client.GetByteArrayAsync(SourceVideoURL);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(b);
                return new   FileStreamResult(stream, "video/mp4");
            }
```

It takes a bit time to load since it seems to use a buffer of some kind.

**2. Based on GetStreamAsync:**

```
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Get(string SourceVideoURL)
             {
                HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
                Stream stream = await _client.GetStreamAsync(SourceVideoURL);
                return new   FileStreamResult(stream, "video/mp4");
             }
```

This one seems to redirect video without buffering.

I am pretty new to asp.net core API, i am not sure what is the preferred approach or maybe i am not using the available tools correctly.

For me most important is fastest streaming (less start delay as possible).

Comment: i'm not happy with this way of doing it, but I know there are better ways - especially because I want to stream other formats than the standards that can be played by the html5 player: http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/16/streaming-video-asynchronously-in-asp-net-core-2-with-web-api/

Comment: @JohanHerstad Funny thing!, My second example (GetStreamAsync) is based on the exact LINK you provided.

Comment: there used to be another class in the old asp.net that was used for streaming, but for some reason it is not in .net core. I think the reason is that .net core has better ways of doing it, at least I remember David Fowler said streaming was easy in core. I just haven't found any examples  so far. I know there's a asp.net core video streaming api for a popular "pirate" streaming app on github somewhere (popcorn something?)

Comment: @JohanHerstad Do you have issues with the method you are using (GetStreamAsync)?

Comment: yes, I ended up rejecting it. I will try to make a streaming api later in the summer for my ubuntu home server, to stream to chromecast. Hopefully using asp.net core

Comment: Did you guys find a solution for this? Further were you able to use html5 video player's seeking feature for this API endpoint implementation? @JohanHerstad